# Longest request in ab benchmark

Tags: python, cherrypy, apachebench

Cross posting from CherryPy mailing list.

Hi all,

I am new to cherrypy and I am trying to understand the results of this following trivial benchmark.
Given this "hello world" app:

```
import cherrypy

class Hello:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'hello'

cherrypy.server.thread_pool = 50
cherrypy.quickstart(Hello())
```

I run `ab -c 10 -n 1000` and I get these results:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        CherryPy/3.2.4
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        5 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   4.494 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      143000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5000 bytes
Requests per second:    222.53 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       44.938 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.494 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          31.08 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1  31.6      0     998
Processing:     2   16 183.1      5    4493
Waiting:        1   15 183.1      5    4492
Total:          2   17 185.7      5    4493

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      7
  75%     11
  80%     13
  90%     18
  95%     21
  98%     24
  99%     25
 100%   4493 (longest request)
```

Note that the longest request takes more than 4 seconds to complete. Given that I set the number of threads to 50 in the app, and that ab uses 10 concurrent requests, I would expect cherrypy to handle it easily. What am I missing?
I tried with different #threads and concurrent requests, with similar results.
I'm using CherryPy v.3.2.4

Thanks for your help,
L.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are running ApacheBench on the same machine as your server (localhost).  So, it's not an accurate benchmark, as ApacheBench is eating up resources on the same machine it is testing.

Is your server CPU-bound?  If you are CPU bound, It's possible the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) is biting you (CherrPy is using multithreading, not multiprocessing).  It will cause you to only make use of one CPU core at a time, and could be causing the outlier you are seeing.

When running benchmarks, always check resources (cpu, network, disk, etc) on both the server under test and the load generating machine.

A better benchmark would be: run `ab` from a remote machine with a fast network connection to your server (make sure machines are on the same LAN so network I/O doesn't factor in much, and run for > 1000 requests so you get a test that's longer than 5 seconds and gives you time to monitor.

Comment: The test is very light on memory, of course, and CPUs (4) work at 50% each: so, not particularly intensive, either, afaict. What surprises me is also the max connection time, 4493ms, as if one of the requests was left waiting without being processed. Longer tests show very similar results.

Comment: hmm.. are you looking at individual CPU core usage?, or just avg. of all cores.  It can sometimes be misleading if a machine is cpu-bound with just one core pegged, so an an avg reported by a tool like `top` would make you think it's fine.

Comment: Actually, I am using a sys monitor that shows graphs for each core. If it's super-accurate, I wouldn't know. But if this was the cause, why would just very few requests be affected and the vast majority run thousands of times faster?